# Read environment neutral Configuration Value from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, configuration-files

I have an env. neutral configuration which is EnableEmailCheck. If the EnableEmailCheck= true then the email validation will takes place and if it is set to false application will not do the email validation.

I need to understand how to do something like that in nodejs

1. What format the configuration file should be ? I think I can keep the key value pair it in .json file
2. How can I read this configuration value from nodejs
3. If the value of the configuration file is changed is it required to restart the nodejs app server to reflect the changes

This configuration value will get changed if there is an issue in the emailvalidation functionality. Then the value will be switched off; in this case it will be set to false by and application engineer.

Comment: And how is json better than javascript itself, or in other words, what's wrong with having your configuration in a separate js file which you can simply require and assign to a config variable?

Comment: It's a bit tricky with require when you want to dinamically load it when it changes.

Comment: There is require.cache, which is a hash table containing all the current loaded modules. Clear the module and then load it again using require().  Something like this: delete require.cache[require.resolve(moduleName)]; var myModule = require(moduleName);

Comment: Isn't harder to write that file? need module.exports etc, maybe someone else will modify it, and knows just he must write a json to a file, not to create a module.

Comment: It could be as simple as this:  var configs = {}; configs.a = 'value a'; configs.b = 'value b'; module.exports = configs;   // then the change would just be the values of configs.a and configs.b when someone needs to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I would save it in json format and add a watch on it:
config.json content:

```
{
  "env":
   {
     "EnableEmailCheck": true;
   }
}
```

Loading config.json file at start and when it changes:

```
var config = null;
var fs = require('fs');

function loadConfig(fileName )
{
   var data = fs.readFileSync( fileName  );
   return JSON.parse( data );
}
function useConfig( )
{
  if( config.env.EnableEmailCheck )
  {
    // do your stuff;
  } 

}
//load it at start
config = loadConfig("config.json");
useConfig();

//add watch for changes
fs.watchFile("config.json", function () 
{
  config = loadConfig("config.json");
  useConfig();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. I have a concern here. Is it fine to call readFileSync() method as it is synchronous.

Comment: When working with files, i rather call Sync functions, to make sure i read it right away. But in this example shouldn't make any difference, both, sync and async options are fine. Just you may need some adjustments on async way, like parsing file data inside the callback.

Comment: Agree.. in this situation I would like to know the best approach.